# How to fix link error under CMake for class QX11Info on Mac OS X

Tags: osx, linker, qt

I'm trying to build [kxstitch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kxstitch/), which is designed for Linux, on OS X.  I've gotten most of the way there by installing MacPorts, XCode, KDE, etc. and making minor changes to the build file, but am getting this error at the final stage of building the project:

```
Linking CXX executable kxstitch.app/Contents/MacOS/kxstitch
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QX11Info::display()", referenced from:
      Editor::keyPressAlphabet(QKeyEvent*) in Editor.o
```

The key line in the build script is:

> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix` .. && make
>   -j${THREADS}

Here is [CMakeLists.txt](http://kxstitch.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=kxstitch/kxstitch;a=blob_plain;f=CMakeLists.txt;hb=a7734f962ee20a8dcc00dbab168f21a9fa395719).

The missing symbol seems to be part of Qt.  As part of installing KDE through MacPorts, many Qt-related packages were installed, including qt4-mac, qt4-mac-devel, and qt4-x11.  The output of cmake includes:

```
-- Looking for QT_MAC_USE_COCOA
-- Looking for QT_MAC_USE_COCOA - found
-- Found Qt-Version 4.8.2
--  -> QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE is /opt/local/bin/qmake
--  -> QT_INCLUDE_DIR is /opt/local/include
--  -> QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR is /opt/local/include/QtCore
--  -> QT_BINARY_DIR is /opt/local/bin
--  -> QT_LIBRARY_DIR is /opt/local/lib
--  -> QT_PLUGINS_DIR is /opt/local/share/qt4/plugins
--  -> QT_MKSPECS_DIR is /opt/local/share/qt4/mkspecs
```

I'd be grateful for any advice on how to proceed.

UPDATE: I've since read about [a problem with the QtGui library on OS X](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-tickets/2009-March/026151.html), although I don't know how to translate the solution to CMAKE.

Comment: I tried tagging this "cmake" but the tag didn't exist, and I don't have enough reputation here to create it.

Comment: a linking problem can be often restricted to 3 scenarios: you are using the wrong library or you are using the wrong compiler or you are using the wrong linking options, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062403/gcc-dies-trying-to-compile-64bit-code-on-osx-10-6 and see if this helps

Comment: I found out there's a known issue with QtGui on OS X [https://trac.macports.org/ticket/18724] and was able to remove the references to the library.  I'm inclined to delete this question because I no longer care about the answer but wanted to at least reply to your comment, which I appreciate.

Comment: don't do that, answer the question yourself and leave this question open for future references.

Comment: I can't answer the question myself, since I still don't know how to use QtGui on OS X with CMake, although I do understand the problem better than I did before.

Comment: it's your choice, maybe just leave this one opened for a day :)